# Expo Router, Navigator at "XYZ" has no children

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I am constantly having trouble having migrated to Expo 48 with File Based routing.  When I add a simple route, it usually is not picked up.

I just added `profile` page which is from the main header.

When I navigate I get the error:

> Navigator at "/(auth)/profile" has no children.

The other screen in the same Stack, `results`, works fine.  I copied the logic over to profile, so I am not sure what the difference is...

I have my file structure as follows:

[image: file structure]

---

my root layout is:

```js
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <AllProviders>
        <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </AllProviders>
  );
}
```

Then, my `(auth)` group layout is now updated to include `profile` Screen:

```js
<Stack
   screenOptions={{
      headerRight: () => (user ? <HeaderRight /> : undefined),
   }}
>
   <Stack.Screen
      name="results"
      options={{
         presentation: 'modal',
      }}
/>
    <Stack.Screen
       name="profile"
    />
</Stack>
```

The `HeaderRight` component does this to generate a navigation action:

```js
return (
    <View
      onPress={() => router.push('/profile')} // this is when the error is seen
    />
  );
```

This is not part of profile flow, but the `(tabs)` layout is:

```js
export default function TabLayout() {
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        title: '',
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Search',
          tabBarIcon: () => <Entypo name="magnifying-glass" size={24} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen name="other" />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

The profile layout is:

```js
export default function ProfilePage() {
  return <Slot />;
}
```

and the profile view is:

```js
const Profile = () => {
  const user = useAuth();

  return <Typography>{user.user?.user_metadata.name}</Typography>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you `export default` everything that is your main route entry.